# Почему я не могу переименовать переменную?

Tags: python, pycharm

Подскажите, почему не могу изменить название переменной?

Делаю обычную операцию:

- выделяю переменную,
- зажимаю shift + f6,
- нажимаю refactor

Изменяется только выделенная переменная.

Перед рефакторингом выдает такое сообщение:

> "Selected element is used from non-project files. These usages won't
> be renamed. Proceed anyway?"

В гугле особо ничего не нашел по этому предупреждению...

Comment: Тыкаете на Превью и смотрите что там поменяется, если не нравится что-то, исключаете его из замены. Или вовсе отменяете рефактор, после снова вызываете рефактор через Shift+F6, выбираете другую область, например не проект, а файл и делайте переименование

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

В выпадающем списке **Scope** диалогового окна **Rename** переключите с `All places` на `Project files`